# How can I turn the words in to number for graph?

Tags: r

Select the Department that you work for b   c   d

```
Biological Sciences 2   Satisfied   Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied
Biological Sciences 1   Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied  Somewhat dissatisfied
Biological Sciences 9   Somewhat satisfied  Satisfied
Biological Sciences 30  Very satisfied  Somewhat satisfied
Biological Sciences 1   Very satisfied  Satisfied
Biological Sciences 3   Somewhat satisfied  Somewhat satisfied
Biological Sciences 1   Satisfied   Satisfied
Biological Sciences 14  Very satisfied  Somewhat satisfied
Biological Sciences 25  Somewhat dissatisfied   Dissatisfied
Biological Sciences 2   Very satisfied  Very satisfied
Biological Sciences 14  Satisfied   Somewhat satisfied
Biological Sciences 8   Very satisfied  Very satisfied
```

I want to turn the satisfied and other into number to make a graph in R.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide more detail about what you want to do and what you've tried? At the moment your question is very unclear and it will be hard to find someone who can help you.

Comment: If the words are not arbitrary words but a specific set of words `(Very|Somewhat)? satisfied` those are called "Factors" in R. See e.g. this youtube video on how to handle them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NOlgZLoojE . More details here: https://www.guru99.com/r-factor-categorical-continuous.html

Answer (score 0):

Not only are those values factors, they are *ordered* factors, a.k.a [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data).

In the future, if you could use `dput()` when you share your data, that would be great, in the absence of that I'll be using this representation:

```
tab <- structure(list(Course=c("Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences",
    "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences",
    "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences",
    "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences", "Biological Sciences",
    "Biological Sciences"), Value=c(2L, 1L, 9L, 30L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 25L, 2L, 14L,
    8L), "Lik-1"=c("Satisfied", "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
    "Somewhat satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied",
    "Satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Somewhat dissatisfied", "Very satisfied",
    "Satisfied", "Very satisfied"), "Lik-2"=c("Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
    "Somewhat dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied",
    "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Dissatisfied",
    "Very satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Very satisfied")), class="data.frame",
    row.names=c(NA, -12L))
```

To convert the two Lik columns to ordinal we need to specify the order of the levels. I'll assume it's something like this:

```
# From low to high
lv <- c("Very dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Somewhat dissatisfied", 
        "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied", 
        "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied" )
```

To just convert one column we could have done `ordered(tab[, 3], levels=lv)`, but as we want to do more than one it makes sense to loop over them using `lapply()`.

```
# We assume the two columns use the same set of ordinals
tab[,3:4] <- lapply(tab[,3:4], ordered, levels=lv)
```

I don't know how you want to plot it (potentially a separate question), but one way could be like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(2.5, 2.5, 0.5, 0.5), mgp=c(1.5, 0.5, 0))
plot(tab[,c(2, 3)])
plot(tab[,c(2, 4)])
```

[image]

But if you just want the numeric values, it's as simple as using `as.numeric()`

```
sapply(tab[,3:4], as.numeric)
#       Lik-1 Lik-2
#  [1,]     6     4
#  [2,]     4     3
#  [3,]     5     6
#  [4,]     7     5
#  [5,]     7     6
#  [6,]     5     5
#  [7,]     6     6
#  [8,]     7     5
#  [9,]     3     2
# [10,]     7     7
# [11,]     6     5
# [12,]     7     7
```